# Are wallets compatible with different clients?

Tags: wallet, multibit

If I create *.wallet file in MultiBit, encrypt it with password and transfer some coins to it - does it tie me to this particular client, or can I open *.wallet file in any client

Answer (score 1):

Almost every client has the option to export your Private keys.

MultiBit also has this option.

You can think of a wallet file as a container for your Private Keys and a list of your transactions. This wallet may be in a different format for different clients, but you can always export your Private key, and that is what matters most.

Bitcoin-qt has a wallet with a [key pool](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/746/how-should-you-backup-your-wallet) and addresses that does not show. The best way to move your coins is to send them to a new address in your new wallet. But if you have a favorite address you want to keep, you can export from the Console with "dumpprivkey".

[Here is my answer, how to export from every client](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13687/which-bitcoin-wallets-let-you-export-to-a-universal-wallet-format/13823#13823)

But there are also services that keep the Private keys.  These services do not allow export.

- Coinbase
- Coinkite (You get your private keys - but encrypted)

Answer (score 1):

Different clients *may* have different wallet formats.   Some do, some don't. If you want to use a new client, create a new wallet for that client and transfer the coins to it.